# Get current Hour/Minute/Secong/Millisecond using timezone of some specific city like America/Mexico_City in swift 3 xcode

Tags: datetime, swift3, calendar, nstimezone, xcode9.1

Here, I want to get current **Hour/Minute/Secong/Millisecond** using timezone of some *specific city* like **America/Mexico_City** using swift 3 xcode. I tried to get current Time-hrs/min/sec/millisec of Mexico city like,

```
    let date = Date()
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "America/Mexico_City")! /* Something wrong here */

    hrOfDay = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    curMin = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    curSec = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    curMillSec = Int(Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)) /* this should be fetched using calendar object */
    print("hours = \(hrOfDay):\(curMin):\(curSec):\(curMillSec)")
```

But I'm unable to get current time of some specific city like MexicoCity. So, Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

TimeZone.init(identifier: "America/Mexico_City")

'America/Mexico_City' is ID, not a name.

so, you can compare to get TimeZone ID by City name from list:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/master/timezones.json
```

Ref: `https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED FINALLY**

**Step 1:**
Using this [LINK](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/master/timezones.json) find the city/country abbreviation **abbr**.

**Step 2:** 
Using the link mentioned in *step 1*, you will get JsonObject as response like example for mexico city:

```
{
"value": "Central Standard Time (Mexico)",
"abbr": "CDT",
"offset": -5,
"isdst": true,
"text": "(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey",
"utc": [
  "America/Bahia_Banderas",
  "America/Cancun",
  "America/Merida",
  "America/Mexico_City",
  "America/Monterrey"
]
}
```

**Step 3:** So use this **abbr key value** like *TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "CDT")* which is clearly mentioned below.

```
func initVars(){

    var date = Date()
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "CDT")!
    hrOfDay = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    curMin = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    curSec = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    curMillSec = calendar.component(.nanosecond, from: date) // may need to convert NANOSECOND to Millisecond // this should be fetchhed using calendat obj
    print("TESTING Current Time = \(hrOfDay):\(curMin):\(curSec):\(curMillSec)")

}
```

**So Finally**, as result you will get like:

```
TESTING Current Time = 10:39:17:812892973
```

Current Mexico time: *10:39 AM Thursday, November 16, 2017 (CST) Time in Mexico City, CDMX, Mexico*

Comment: This is going to be **very** unreliable. Time zone abbreviations are not unique and are duplicated in different parts of the world. Time zones created with abbreviations will be different depending on where. the user is located.